# Set variable dynamically in flow is not working

Tags: java, cxf, mule, ws-security

I need to access a service using the JAX WS client.
I need to provide a authentication token along with the call.

I used the below configuration to pass a token in my Mule flow, but it is not working.

```
<cxf:jaxws-client operation="addProduct"
     clientClass="org.example.productservice.ProductSService"
     port="ProductSvcPort" >            
        <cxf:ws-security>
            <cxf:ws-config>
                <cxf:property key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
                <cxf:property key="user" value="#[flowVars['token']]" />
                ...........
```

Please help me understand what missing here. I could see that the invocation variable "token" is good and existing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known issue: http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6796